# how to use variable in "when" statement in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use  a variable in when statement in ansible ,
my code snippet looks like this :

```
- name: git repo for non prod env
  git:
    repo=http://url/repo.git
    dest=/opt/dest
    version={{ bld_env }}
  when: ( "{{ bld_env }}" == "rc" ) or ( "{{ bld_env }}" == "sandbox" ) or ( "{{ bld_env }}" == "dev" ) or ( "{{ bld_env }}" == "qa" )
```

This is not working and gives an a error as :

```
The offending line appears to be:

    version={{ bld_env }}
  when: "{{ bld_env }}" == "rc"
                        ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Let me know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you don't have to use `"{{ bld_env }}" == "rc"`.

Just compare variable to value `bld_env == "rc"` and so on as it is written in [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)